# Calculating all potencies of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I've stumbled across this problem while reading my textbook (chapter eigenvalues)

Calculate all potencies of $A$ and $A+aE$

$ a \in K$ and $A \in K-Vectorspace$

$ A=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
 \quad$ and hence $\quad A+aE = \begin{pmatrix}
a & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & a & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a 
\end{pmatrix}\qquad $

It can't be $ A^{n} = A \cdots A$ but what are potencies of $A$ and $A+aE$, if this question popped up during the chapter Eigenvalues?

Comment: Potency of a matrix is (from what I remember) the smallest $n$ s.t. all diagonal entries of $A^n$ are strictly positive. However, if this is what is meant it seems strange to talk about all potencies. Sure its not all powers? This makes more sense as $A^n$ has a very simple form up to $A^5 = 0$.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by potency, if none of the answers so far are correct.

Comment: I don't know what potency means. Thats why I'm asking. I can only tell you that this question showed at the end of the chapter eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't talking of *powers*, are you?

In that case you have
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
A^{2} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, \\
A^{3} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, \quad
A^{4} =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},
$$
and $A^{k} = 0$ for $k \ge 5$.

Then since $E A = A E$, you have
\begin{align}
(a E + A)^{n}
&=
\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (a E)^{n-k} A^{k}
\\&=
a^{n} E + n a^{n-1} A + \binom{n}{2} a^{n-2} A^{2} + \binom{n}{3} a^{n-3} A^{3} + \binom{n}{4} a^{n-4} A^{4}
\\&=
\begin{bmatrix}
a^{n} & n a^{n-1} & \binom{n}{2} a^{n-2} & \binom{n}{3} a^{n-3} & \binom{n}{4} a^{n-4} \\
0 & a^{n} & n a^{n-1} & \binom{n}{2} a^{n-2} & \binom{n}{3} a^{n-3}\\
0 & 0 & a^{n} & n a^{n-1} & \binom{n}{2} a^{n-2}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & a^{n} & n a^{n-1}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a^{n} 
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: The solution looks fine but I can't tell how this is related to eigenvalues?

Comment: Take any matrix $B$. Suppose you have to compute a high power $B^{n}$ of $B$. IF all of the eigenvalues of $B$ are in the underlying field, you can conjugate $B$ to a matrix that consists of diagonal blocks of a form similar to $a E + A$ (of various dimensions), where the $a$ are the eigenvalues. The exewrcise shows that computing powers of these $A$ is easy. So you compute those powers, and then conjugate back to get $B^{n}$. I use a simplified example of this kind to justify the introduction of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, as in the next comment [follows in the next comment]

Comment: [Follows from previous comment] I ask my students: would you prefer to have to compute the tenth power of $\begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&2\\\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\1&1\\\end{bmatrix}$? Since the second matrix conjugates to the first one, it is nearly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The potency of a non-negative matrix $A$ is the smallest $n>0$ such that $diag(A^n) > 0$.

So for $A$, there is not any potency; for $A+aE$, if $a>0$, the potency is $1$, and if $a<0$, the potency is $2$.

Comment: this is the only definition of potency that I know in mathematic. I didn't see other meanings. sorry about that.